# `SettingWithCopyWarning` understanding

Tags: python, pandas, copy

I have code as below.i get bunch of `SettingWithCopyWarning` messages. But if i check 3 dataframes after the last statement, only `df_numeric['class']` has value 99. In other two dataframes `class` value remains unchanged. WHy? i thought that due to `SettingWithCopyWarning`, after the last statement `class` values in all dataframe would change

please explain what is going on

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['Alex',10,5,0],['Bob',12,4,1],['Clarke',13,6,0],['brke',15,1,0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age','weight','class'],dtype=float) 

df_numeric=df.select_dtypes(include='number')#, exclude=None)[source]
df_non_numeric=df.select_dtypes(exclude='number')

df_non_numeric['class']=df_numeric['class'].copy()

df_numeric['class']=99
```

Comment: so you want `df['class']=df_numeric['class']` ?? also is it not same as your previous question?

Comment: i want to understand what is going on. I thought that `df['class']=df_numeric['class']`, but it is not. why? what do `SettingWithCopyWarning` indicate?

Comment: May be you want to go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas it is explained nicely with all examples

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer here. It's the most common **warning** in `pandas`.

Just like [Understanding SettingwithCopyWarning in pandas](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning) said, `pandas` informs you that your operation might not have worked as expected and that you should check the result to make sure you haven’t made a mistake.

---

#### The reason for `SettingwithCopyWarning`

`SettingwithCopyWarning` usually happens when you are **trying to assign new values to a subset `df2` of the original data frame `df1`**

But the **original** dataframe `df1` hasn't changed at all!

[image]
[Picture borrows from [Understanding SettingwithCopyWarning in pandas](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning)]

#### How to nail it down?

1. I recommend you go through this post [Understanding SettingwithCopyWarning in pandas](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning) with detailed explanation and example code
2. Like @anky_91 said, you can go through the posts in your comment list

---

Hope you go through all the mess!